# Open closed principle in a method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC project wherein I need to follow the open closed principles.

The project converts a .csv file to a model from a database, but in the future we might also have to convert Excel files to the same model from the database.

Now, I have this code in the `Convertor` class:

```
public class Convertor 
{
    private static ICompanyRepository companyRepository;

    /// <summary>
    /// converts the uploaded csv data to Company model
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePath">the csv data</param>
    /// <returns>a list of Compamy model</returns>
    public List<Company> ConvertCsvToCompanyModel(string filePath)
    { 
        companyRepository = new CompanyRepository(new ImportContext());
        List<Company> companies = new List<Company>();

        //Read the contents of CSV file.
        string csvData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        //we skip the first row, because it contain the header         
        var csvLines = csvData.Split('\n').Skip(1);

        //Execute a loop over the rows.
        foreach (string row in csvLines)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
            {
                if (!companyRepository.CompanyExist(row.Split(',')[0]))//check if already contains the ExternalId
                {
                    companies.Add(new Company
                    {
                        //CounterPartId
                        ExternalId = row.Split(',')[0],
                        //Name
                        TradingName = row.Split(',')[1],
                        //IsBuyer
                        IsForwarder = Convert.ToBoolean(Enum.Parse(typeof(BooleanAliases), row.Split(',')[2])),
                        //IsSeller
                        IsCarrier = Convert.ToBoolean(Enum.Parse(typeof(BooleanAliases), row.Split(',')[3])),
                        //Phone
                        Phone = row.Split(',')[4],
                        //Fax
                        Fax = row.Split(',')[5]
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        return companies;
    }
}
```

Can you please give me some hints how to change this code in order to follow the open closed principle? In the future, as I mentioned, it is possible to need a converter for Excel files, too.

Answer (score 2):

Before reviewing micro-design we may focus on overall architecture. You already know that in future you will also need to read an Excel file, it may be a good moment to introduce an abstract base class (or an interface) to abstract this detail from the client:

```
public abstract class Convertor
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<Company> ToCompanyModel(string path);
}
```

Note few changes:

- I'm using `Convertor` as base class name then you will have, for example, `CsvConvertor`, no need to repeat any of those information in the method name.
- I'm returning `IEnumerable<Company>` instead of `List<Company>`. The effective type you're using to store the result is an implementation detail, here I picked the most generic one but you may return `IList<Company>` as well (what if, for example, you will decide to store `Company` as an hash-table to detect duplicates?)

How to create the right `Convertor` instance? I assume you have DI in-place then you may have a factory class which will create the right instance according to file extension (assuming you're sure you will need Excel files). Something similar to:

```
public interface IConvertorFactory
{
    Convertor Create(string path);
}
```

If not then simply use DI to get the converter instance without any factory. You now have another problem: testing. Do you want to unit test your converter using physical files? Of course you need to but it's also handy to work with in-memory representations then you may add an overload with `StreamReader`:

```
public abstract class Convertor
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<Company> ToCompanyModel(string path);
    public abstract IEnumerable<Company> ToCompanyModel(StreamReader stream);
}
```

Default implementation may simply open the stream reading line-by-line and you won't need to worry about file size because it won't read everything in memory. Another benefit is that you can check for reader logic without mixing with I/O logic (and this is good to write extensive testing).

---

`ICompanyRepository companyRepository` has no reason to be `static`, you just make your class not thread-safe without any other benefit.

You're not doing any error handling. Things may go wrong and caller will get unknown exception. You'd better handle possible errors and return a single well-known exception (let's say `InvalidDataException`) with all the required details. Do not forget to **document** exceptions you may throw. You may even decide to ignore errors in one row and continue processing.

You're splitting each line with `row.Split()` multiple times, it's a waste: do it once.

To reduce nesting you can use `continue` and filters (example, again, without error handling):

```
foreach (string row in csvLines.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
{
    var fields = row.Split(',');

    var externalId = fields[0];

    if (companyRepository.CompanyExist(externalId))
        continue;

    // ...
}
```

However the truth is that you do not need to do CSV parsing by hand. In Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly (if you do not want to use an external library) you already have a well-tested and complete implementation:

```
using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(stream))) 
{
    parser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });

    // Skip header
    parser.ReadLine();

    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        var fields = parser.ReadFields();

        // Same as before
    }
```

Note that you can catch `MalformedLineException` to handle errors and you can specify exactly the expected type of each field (if you want to). Also text fields may be enclosed in quotes, use `TextFieldParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes` property to instruct the parser. Blank lines are, by default, skipped and you may even use comments (see `TextFieldParser.CommentTokens` property).

Very last note: if CSV file is generated by Excel then be aware that it won't always use the comma as delimiter but the current list separator character (see `CultureInfo.TextInfo.ListSeparator`).

Answer (score -2):

When you actually need the Excel feature, you'll know exactly what you need. Right now, you will only guess and do it wrong.

This might means 2 things:

- You'll have to change it in the future, because it wasn't like you guessed.
- Eventually, you won't need that feature and have made it complex unnecesarily.